# How to create and call a variable for PostgresSQL/psql connections within batch file?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql

I have a single batch file that runs various psql and ogr2ogr (spatial/GIS) commands within PostgreSQL databases. I run identical commands across two identical databases (dev & test). I'd like to store my PostreSQL connection info in a single variable and call it to run my psql commands. That way I can simply comment out the connection (dev or test) which I'm not currently using.

The reason I'm using this workflow is because I also run ogr2ogr commands in the same script, which successfully uses a simply batch variable.

**Scenario 1: Manually update connections. This works but is tedious to update**

```
::Run commands in DEV Server/DB
psql U UserName -h 99.99.999.999 -d MyDB -c "some sql command1"
ogr2ogr command 1
psql U UserName -h 99.99.999.999 -d MyDB -c "some sql command2"
psql U UserName -h 99.99.999.999 -d MyDB -c "some sql command3"

::Run commands in TEST Server/DB
psql U UserName -h 88.88.888.888 -d MyDB -c "some sql command1"
ogr2ogr command 1
psql U UserName -h 88.88.888.888 -d MyDB -c "some sql command2"
psql U UserName -h 88.88.888.888 -d MyDB -c "some sql command3"
```

**Scenarios 2: I would like to set DB connections in 1 one place. Then I can run all commands and switch between DBs by simply commenting out 1 line and re-running the batch.**

```
\SET dbConnect "-U UserName -h 99.99.999.999 -d MyDevDB"
::\SET dbConnect "-U UserName -h 88.88.888.888 -d MyTestDB"

psql dbConnect -c "some sql command1"
ogr2ogr command 1
psql dbConnect -c "some sql command2"
psql dbConnect -c "some sql command3"
```

I've tried several options include the -v, set, and /set to no avail. I've researched these cases below, but am still struggling. Ideally I'd like to store and call the variables in one location, in one file.

[psql passed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570248/psql-passed-variable)
[How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)
[PostgreSQL Connection URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/postgresql-connection-url)

Comment: It may not be the answer you are looking for but I suggest you might try some simple Python which should provide what you ask, and it would allow advancement in your setup

Comment: Did you try setting environment variables? It is the most upvoted answer in your second reference.

Comment: @Slumdog. A python script may be the way to go if I can't stick to a single .bat file with my desired functionality. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński  I did explore that option but wish to run this a standalone, single file instead of having a 2nd file to reference. Thanks for the reply!